# What tense should I use after "after" to describe something in the future if the sentence is past tense?

Tags: tense

Is it correct to use either **present tense** and **present perfect tense** after **after**?

Here's the sentence:

> I borrowed his laptop but promised him that I would give it back later
> after **I finish typing my essay.**

I'm in a dilemma whether I should use present tense or present perfect. And since the construction is like a report, I mean I reported that I had borrowed his laptop bla bla bla... I also have a thought that I should use past tense.

Could you tell me the appropriate tense I should use? Also I hope you don't mind mentioning other alternatives (tenses that are probable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a British English speaker, I would say:

> I borrowed his laptop but promised him that I would give it back after I had finished typing my essay.

Or, if the situation is still ongoing, you could say

> I've borrowed his laptop but promised him that I will give it back after I've finished typing my essay.

Comment: I (an American English speaker) would be more likely to say "I borrowed...after I finished typing".  I wonder if this is a regional variation.

Comment: @stangdon - Yes - that's why I specified BrE, knowing that Americans often use tenses differently.